# How to convert column type from varchar to date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

I have `varchar` data type column and `date` data type column.

I have to update `varchar` column data into `date` column in PostgreSQL.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 81):

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> TYPE DATE 
using to_date(<columnname>, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE tableName SET dateColumn=to_date(varcharColumn, 'DD MM YYYY')
```

Assuming you are saving "07 04 2010"

You can find further examples and explanation in the documentation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Solution is correct, the url to a very old manual is a little hmmmm.... 8.1 will not be supported as of November 2010. Better use a newer version.

Answer (score 4):

syntax for typecasting:

```
alter table table_name alter column_name 
   type converting_data_type using(column_name::converting_data_type)
```

converting from varchar to date

```
alter table table_name 
  alter column_name type date using(column_name::date)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert column type from `timestamp` to `date` in postgresql with explicit typecast:

Explicit typecast allows our existing data to be converted to our new type when the column type is updated.

There is slight change in syntax for explicit typecast for keyword `USING`

Syntax:

> ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type
> USING expression;

eg. Suppose we have table *user_data* with a column *date_of_birth* which took `timestamp` earlier, but now we want it to store only date.

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE user_data
ALTER COLUMN date_of_birth TYPE date 
USING date_of_birth::date;
```