# Calendar in php and html

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I'm developing a calendar with reservations in HTML and PHP (I do not know how to do otherwise). Only I have a problem with formats and data.
First of all I have problems regarding the date, I had to set it as "integer" on Postgresql and consequently on the form html as text (and this is the first thing I would like to change).
Same thing regarding the timetable.

form.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="invia")
{
  $titolo = addslashes($_POST['titolo']);
  $testo = addslashes($_POST['testo']);
  $str_data = strtotime($_POST['data']);
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO appuntamenti (titolo,testo,str_data ) VALUES ('$titolo', '$testo', '$str_data')";
  if($result = pg_query($sql))
  {
    echo "Inserimento avvenuto con successo.<br>
    Vai al <a href=\"index.php\">Calendario</a>";
  }
}else{
  ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Titolo:<br>
<input name="titolo" type="text"><br>
Testo:<br>
<textarea name="testo" cols="30" rows="8"></textarea><br>
Data:<br>
<input name="data" type="text" value="gg-mm-aaaa"><br>
Orario:<br>
<input name="hour" type="time" ><br> -->
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
  <?php
}
?>
```

appuntamenti.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['day']) && is_numeric($_GET['day']))
{
  $day = $_GET['day'];
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM appuntamenti WHERE str_data=$day";
  $result = pg_query($sql);
  if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($fetch = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id = stripslashes($fetch['id']);
      $titolo = stripslashes($fetch['titolo']);
      $testo = stripslashes($fetch['testo']);
      $data = date("d-m-Y", $fetch['str_data']); 
      $hour = date("hh-mm", $fetch['hour']);
      echo "Appuntamenti del <b>$data</b> delle <b>$hour</b><br>" . $titolo . "<br>" . $testo . "<br>
      <a href=\"cancella.php?id=$id\">Cancella</a> |
      <a href=\"modifica.php?id=$id\">Modifica</a>
      <hr>";
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

In this case i receive the date in the correct way ( but the user inserts this like text, and i don't want to do this. ) and the hours likes 0101-0101. 
How can i solve?
Thanks you all

Comment: Review https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html.  I see no good reason to store dates and time in an integer format.  Then for your HTML, look up datepicker and datetimepicker or other solutions for date and time gadgets for your pages.

Comment: I saw your document link but don't understand how to impost in the db. Now i try to implement with datetimepicker ;)

Comment: Do you have any control on the database?  You would need to `alter table` to change the column data types, and fix any data already in there.

Comment: Yes but i tried "date", "time", "timestamp" but i retrieve an error

Comment: Ex PostgreSQL alter: https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/tables/alter_table.php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592412/how-to-convert-column-type-from-varchar-to-date-in-postgresql

Comment: Also, please learn how to use bind variables instead of all the addslashes junk-- it's a lot easier to code in the long run